# div button to slide in and off screen (depending user's mouse)

Tags: html, css

I have a div with class .`side-buttons`. This div will slide in and off when user's mouse hover over the div. I was wondering how can I hide the div completely and say when the user's mouse is in the area it would slide in?

I tried getting the off the screen but that wouldn't work as it would only work when my mouse on the div

This is my website - http://smati.ca/test/index.html (Don't click continue but instead click around the popup modal to get off the modal overlay. There you can see the div in action)

Here's my css code :

```
.side-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: 55%;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.side-buttons:hover {
    right: 0px;
}

.side-buttons a {
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33a9c3 15%, #b1ccbb 100%);
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.side-buttons a small {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.side-buttons a:hover,
.side-buttons a:focus,
.side-buttons a:active {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33a9c3 15%, #b1ccbb 100%);
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

.side-buttons a:nth-child(2) {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #de3c88 15%, #f0a473 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo element, like this

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  right: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 0s 0.5s;
  border: 1px dotted gray;   /*  added for demo purpose  */
}
div:hover {
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
div:hover::after {
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Here is another option, that might be easier to add to your existing solution

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  width: 170px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.5s, padding-left 0s 0.5s;
  border: 1px dotted gray;   /*  added for demo purpose  */
}
.wrapper:hover {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 0;
  transition: width 0.5s, padding-left 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content">
    Some text and/or images<br>
    or anything else needed
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: a little bit confused how to apply this to the right side of my existing code

Comment: @drifterOcean19 The pseudo trick work the same no matter left or right ... updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this too i.e wrapping it by a `div` and performing that `slide-in` and `slide-out` effect on `child div` as below,

```css
#bx{
  width:210px;
  height:120px;
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  right:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#bx > .b{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:120px;
  background:blue;
  right:-200px;
  transition:0.6s ease;
}

#bx:hover > .b{
  right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bx">
<div class="b">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This new stackoverflow layout doesn't have that accept tick. I can only vote it up.

Comment: @rory-h Okay thanks :-) But I couldn't find any update documentation on tick on new layout.